Shower Grout Repair in a Rental
I’m renting so I don’t want to do any major project - just looking for a quick fix that will last for at least a year or 2.
The grout in my shower is not sealed & mold grows quickly. It has become very difficult to get rid of only to come back in a week. Obvs I need to seal the grout. However small pieces of grout are missing in spots & some grout lines are recessed due to cleaning erosion.
I want to fix it so it’s no longer an eyesore to me & a bed for mold to grow. I don’t have the patience, time or energy to seek perfection or even proper protocol. It wasn’t done right the first time so it’s not on me. My landlord does NOT care & she will NOT pay to have it done. I am looking for guidance and recommendations on HOW to do it MYSELF.
I don’t want to scrape a bunch of old grout out & then apply new. Is there a product that can go overtop existing (recessed) grout lines? & fill in missing gaps along existing grout?
Reviews on fast drying grout (repair kits) in tubes indicate limited longevity - like a week.
I’m looking for an EASY, QUICK fix that will last a year or 2.
I have no plans of addressing all the grout in the shower, only the problem areas. I do not want to remove the existing grout if AT ALL possible.
What are my options?

Mold might be a health department issue, and they might make your landlord fix it.  Missing grout might mean leaks/rotting of wood and be a building department issue.  You probably also have other legal options/tenant regulations you might be allowed.  It depends on how long you need to stay there.

The answer will also depend on the terms of your rental agreement (even if oral, and not written down) and on the law that applies to this rental property.

She’s a friend so I’m not going either of those routes. I shouldn’t have even mentioned I was a tenant.
